# How to stop js from running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have seen a video tutorial on YouTube about [Dynamic Content](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eziREnZPml4&index=37&list=PLGlcsQuIFMgJBt-4GDm8ZZpR_nnKPW9g4) that when a user reaches the bottom of a page, it automatically loads new div (Something like the facebook homepage). Instead of the intended result, it just keeps on loading. I don't know how to stop that. Here's the full code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function yHandler(){
    // Watch video for line by line explanation of the code
    // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eziREnZPml4
    var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
    var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
    var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
    var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
    if(y >= contentHeight){
        // Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here
        wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData"></div>';
    }
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = contentHeight+" | "+y;
}
window.onscroll = yHandler;

</script>
<style>
div#status{position:fixed; font-size:24px;}
div#wrap{width:800px; margin:0px auto;}
div.newData{height:1000px; background:#09F; margin:10px 0px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="status">0 | 0</div>
<div id="wrap"><img src="temp9.jpg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

To test it on your desktop, make sure you have the image with the name of *temp9.jpg*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a check to see if the content is being fetched, if it is ignore the code until the data has been loaded.

```
var isLoading = false;
function yHandler(){
    if (isLoading) {
       return;
    }
    /* Rest of logic */
}
```

Now when the Ajax call is complete, set `isLoading` back to `false`.

```
$.get( "example.php", function() {
    alert( "success" );
}).done(function() {
    isLoading = false;
});
```